# How to get data from website via API or RSS?

Tags: python, rss

I need to extract data from this website: https://nasdaqbaltic.com/statistics/en/news. from 2010-01-01 until now. RSS gives 100 items at page, so it is just a part. Company TeliaLietuva AB. How to get data from 2010 January until now and store data into XML file? `

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

params = {
    'start': '2005-01-01',
    'end': '2023-10-24',
    'historical': '0',
    '_': '1698143883305',
}

response = requests.get(
    'https://nasdaqbaltic.com/statistics/en/instrument/LT0000123911/trading/chart_price_json',
    params=params,
)

data = json.loads(response.text)["data"]["data"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["date", "price", "volume"])
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], unit="ms")
display(df.head(3))
display(df.tail(3))
```

Output

```
        date                price       volume
0       2005-01-03 14:30:00 0.834106    56282
1       2005-01-04 14:30:00 0.841829    109255
2       2005-01-05 14:30:00 0.845690    200466

        date                price   volume
4762    2023-10-20 13:30:00 1.625   48853
4763    2023-10-23 13:30:00 1.625   52914
4764    2023-10-24 13:30:00 1.625   8361
```

To save the data as XML you can do this:

```
df.to_xml("data.xml")
```

Comment: Actually is not ok it should be structure like this:

    "item": [
        {
            "company": "Snaige",
            "messageUrl": "https://view.news.eu.nasdaq.com/view?id=b8329142afcfca04adabcbe142562ef5b&lang=en&src=listed",
            "published": "2023-10-03 19:00:00 +0300",
            "headline": "Notification on the acquisition of voting rights". Format as in RSS.
        },

Comment: My answer answers your original question. If you have new requirements post a new question. Please also keep in mind that SO is not a code writing service. ;0) What you need now should be something that you very well can derive yourself from the code I proposed.

Comment: So how get combined xml from pages RSS?

Comment: Have you tried the code I have given you? You wanted to get data «via API or RSS». My answer gives you code that yields data from 2005 until today in **one combined dataframe** that you can export to XML.

Comment: Yes, I did. But it about prices not info about in RSS. I am about extracting data from RSS. But it is related with paging. At this moment I extracted data on first page.